# Combine text and xml tag using python's ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, merge, elementtree

I am trying to achieve something as below:

```
<root>
    <parent>Make from <child>12345678</child> this part</parent>
</root>
```

Leading text (i.e. "Make from") followed by a child tag followed by rest of the text (i.e.  "this part") all within a parent tag in the exact sequence

An xml tag of the form : `<parent-tag><leading-text> <child-tag> <trailing-text><parent-tag>`

I am doing something as below, *but the leading text gets overwritten*

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

    root = ET.Element("root")

    b1 = ET.SubElement(root, "parent")
    b1.text = "Make from "
    b2 = ET.SubElement(b1, "child")
    b2.text = "12345678"

    b1.text = " this part"

    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
```

and I get something as below

```
<root>
   <parent> this part <child>12345678</child> </parent>
</root>
```

Cannot find anything to append the trailing text to the existing leading text with the child tag in between.

Any pointers will help!

Comment: " this part" would be the `tail` of the `<child>` element. This is a common "stumbling block". There are many questions about it. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```py
b1.text = " this part"
```

try:

```py
b2.tail = " this part"
```